# Number limit supported by batch files

Tags: batch-file, integer-arithmetic

I was trying to add a 12-digit and an 8-digit number using a batch file. However, it gives the following error- `Invalid number. Numbers are limited to 32-bits of precision`.

What should I do to overcome this obstacle?

If it helps, I was adding them like this-

`set /a z= (%r:~0% + %u:~0%)`

where `r` and `u` contain the numbers to be added in string format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 12-digit number is already outside the boundaries of Int32, which means you just cannot do arithmetic with it in batch files directly.

What you *can* do, is adding the numbers by digit, maintaining a carry, just as you did in primary school. It will be slower, but it works.

Another option is to let other programs do the calculation, e.g. PowerShell:

```
for /f %%x in ('powershell %r:~0% + %u:~0%') do set result=%%x
```

Side note: `%r:~0%` means, I think, »take a substring of `%r%`, starting at character 0, extending to the end of the string«, which is exactly the same as the string itself.

Comment: You can use substrings to get at individual characters from the strings, add them and build up your result string. Or just split the numbers into two halves that still fit into Int32. It's been a while, but I've written a bignum add method in batch once. Don't have access to it now, though.

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly when I used the path address of Powershell rather than the word- Powershell!